# Python_data categorization

Tags: python, substring, categories

I have dataset with columns "Product"- "Quantity" - "Price". The task is - to make new column "Product category", based on matching substring in the "Product" rows.
For this were category lists created: A= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] and B=['e' , 'f' , 'j']
If any word from the category list presents in "Product" rows, category should be assigned.

With the code below, I got the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str' and can't firn thу solution.

```
category=[]

for row in data_exp['product']:
    if row.str.contains('a|b|c|d').any():
        category.append('A')
    if row.str.contains('e|f|j').any():
        category.append('B')
    else:
        category.append('C')

data_exp['category']=category
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
def get_category(s):
    if any(c in s for c in {'a', 'b', 'c'}):
        return 'A'
    elif any(c in s for c in {'d', 'e', 'f'}):
        return 'B'

    return 'C'

df['category'] = df['product'].apply(get_category)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  product category
0       a        A
1       e        B
2       z        C
3       b        A
4       c        A
5       f        B
```

Comment: Yes, it works ))) Thank you! Could you please explain, where my mistake was? i stucked for couple days and really believed that my method was correct ...

Comment: @I.Kov You're having `for row in data_exp['product']:`, but `row` contains single string, not a `pd.Series`.  So that's why you got the error.